# select specific column in all rows from table header class name

Tags: css

In a table all `<th>` are having `class` and `<td>` dont.

Is it possible to  apply the styles from those `<th>` `class` to all its corresponding `<td>`'s  with plain `css` and dont need of any `script`?

Additionally `table` is dynamic and so columns index may differ. So i cant use `nth-child` and only way i can navigate it with `class`.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gX2Wk/)

Any better ideas for cross-browser?

**Update:**

table may have `n` number of columns and not limited to `2` columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle this using `<col>`, http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html#background, only other way I see would need to add the classes everywhere or to use JS.

Comment: Or `<col>`, actually - `<colgroup>` just groups individual columns together.

Comment: @Simon +1 for better idea but anyway in my case i need to handle with `css` alone if that possible

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="a">`Column A`</th>
    `<th class="b">`Column B`</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="a">`aaa`</td>
    <td class="b">`bbb`</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="a">`ccc`</td>
    <td class="b">`ddd`</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you pls check my question again? i need to apply all properties from `class` applied in `<th>` to its corresponding `<td>`'s